# Dynamic URL indexing

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, indexing, seo

I'm building a site with many dynamically created URLs. Basically I have categories and subcategories and I format my link "category/subcategory", however only index.php is being used and content is generated according to the selected categories. There are no direct links to each and every category/subcategory (the generated URL is SEO friendly, no GET parameters whatsoever), I'm trying to achieve a minimalistic design so adding links in bulk is not really an option. Will Google and other search engines be able to index my dynamic pages? The pages are reachable through a select tool where the user can select and/or search for the required categories. I hope i managed to explain my problem properly if not I will try to add some pictures.

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: and how is it off-topic? :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you generate a sitemap file form the database and upload that.  The search engines, will most likely be able to use that instead.  Then you have some control.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84     http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/sitemap.xsd">
 <url>
     <loc>http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/</loc> 
     <lastmod>2005-06-04T00:00:00+00:00</lastmod> 
     <changefreq>monthly</changefreq> 
     <priority>0.6</priority> 
 </url>
 <url>
     <loc>http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/database/progress-database-design-guide/</loc> 
     <lastmod>2005-06-04T00:00:00+00:00</lastmod> 
     <changefreq>monthly</changefreq> 
     <priority>1.0</priority> 
 </url>
 <url>
     <loc>http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/catindex.htm?node=2</loc> 
     <lastmod>2005-05-31T00:00:00+00:00</lastmod> 
     <priority>0.5</priority> 
 </url>
 <url>
     <loc>http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/what-is-new.htm</loc> 
     <lastmod>2005-06-04T08:31:12+00:00</lastmod> 
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
     <priority>1.0</priority> 
 </url>
```

PFE: http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/article.htm?node=133&page=37 (as per comments)

Comment: So, if I generate a sitemap with all the URL-s search engines will index them? Sorry but I'm a 'noob' in this field :)

Comment: I have done a little, but that is how I remember that.  You are basically "helping" the engine figure out the map of the site.  The engines have changed a lot of their algorythms over the last few years, so one cannot be 100% sure.  But I would do that if I have no other options.  Also just have a look at how wordpress does their SEO (which is pretty good - out of the box).  The whole site is a dynamic CMS engine - with dynamic pages, essentially.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for the quick response! I had the false idea that a sitemap can only contain static urls (with real folders). I will check how wordpress handles this situation!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15614/Building-and-Consuming-a-Dynamic-Sitemap-in-ASP-NE suggests that, that is not the case.

Comment: Also, http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/article.htm?node=133&page=37

Answer (score 1):

More important than a sitemap, are links. Allow me to elaborate... My concern from your description is this part:

> *The pages are reachable through a select tool where the user can select and/or search for the required categories.*

Search engines, Google included, don't know these are "dynamic" URLs, nor do they care. The #1 absolute best practice you can/should do to improve SEO is having good, easy to follow, navigation, this includes links. **Not a "select" control.** Links. I can't stress this enough! You can still achieve a drop-down effect if that's what you want for your UX, only the markup **has** to include links. A common implementation is to use a list of links, then do with that list what you wish.

A few articles highlighting the importance of good links and navigation for SEO:

- http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/growing-popularity-and-links
- http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2280170/Why-Links-Remain-Critical-to-SEO-Success

One of hundreds of list-to-dropdown solutions that should fix your SEO issue, without changing your UX:

- http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/

Comment: Also, make sure your navigation works without JavaScript. Using a pure `<select>` approach means that you're probably relying on JavaScript to redirect the user depending on their selection.

Comment: Yes, redirect is with JS. My dropdown is a bit different. The user can select the category and the subcategory and then by pressing search it will redirect to a dynamic URL based on the selected data. Can I add invisible links to all my pages? Or is that bad/stupid?

Comment: It's not stupid, but it *is* bad. Google will penalize you for hiding content and it's terrible for accessibility.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the answer, sadly I can't upvote because I just registered. I think i will stick with Anthony's answer and generate a sitemap, but I will also create a noJS version where I will basically just list all the categories and subcategories with links to them. Hope that would be a decent approach.